# Log method information

Tags: c#, reflection, aop

I have been spending a lot of time trying to find a library that allows to log information about the methods that are being executed. Somehow I feel that all of them are too invasive. Is there any library or code that makes this so simple that I **only need to add a decorator/attribute to the method**?

Here what I would like to have:

```
internal class Calculator
{
    [CustomInterceptor]
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

internal class CustomInterceptor : Attribute
{
     //here some implementation
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    var result = Calculator.Add(10, 2);
    Console.WriteLine($"Result : {result}");
}
```

Desired output

```
Before Add
Result 12
After Add
```

If this can be done with Reflection, please I would prefer that approach since that would imply no need for third party libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a 3rd party library or you need to write a lot of code (ie. create your own library).

Comment: Read about Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP), that could help a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator

Comment: thanks @Igor, if that's the only way I will accept it.

Comment: Good question. I'm so sorry that AOP doesn't get that much love... you may be interested in [this interview to the father of C#](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Anders-Hejlsberg-Dead-Body)

Comment: That's a nice post. thanks @FrancescoB.

Comment: you're welcome, I hope you find a solution